# Assigning properties using RTTI without knowing what type the property is

Tags: delphi, reflection, pascal, rtti

I have some object `newObject` with unknown properties and I want to be able to assign values to its properties without knowing what type the property is.

The best I can do so far is

```
vCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
vType := vCtx.GetType(newObject.ClassType);

for vProp in vType.GetProperties do
begin    
    vPropValue := 'Test Value';

    val := TValue.From<String>( vPropValue);

    vProp.SetValue( newObject , val );
end;
```

Of course, this assumes that the properties are of type `string`

How do I make this more general?

Comment: TValue.From<????>(vPropValue)

Comment: Check the typekind of the property and use the correct TValue?

Comment: How do you want to assign values if you don't know the type?! That does not make any sense.

Comment: One can only wonder what `vPropValue` is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in this case, `vPropValue : String `

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen if the property is anything other than a string?

Comment: @StefanGlienke, I'd like to be able to get the property type from RTTI.
ie: Like using `vProp.PropertyType`

Comment: That's what `TypeKind` is??

Comment: And then do what? Where do the values come from? If you don't know the type you cannot provide a value. Please provide more information in your question to make clear what you want. Currently it's just not clear.

Comment: Suppose that the property is something other than a string, and `vPropValue` is a string, what do you want to happen next? It's not enough to be flexible with the property type. You need to be equally flexible with the incoming value type.

Comment: @sav, please read [this article](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.be/2009/10/ini-persistence-rtti-way.html), it contains useful info, look at the TIniPersist.SetValue function

Comment: @StefanGlienke, This is part of a bigger program. I can handle that part. I just wanted to keep this code simple, because that is the part I am stuck on.

Comment: How are you stuck? vProp has all the info you need. What can't you do?

Comment: I need to know how to do `val := TValue.From<vProp.TypeInfo>( vPropValue);` the correct way

Comment: Again, what type is vPropValue. If the property type is not string, then what? TValue does not convert non assignable types like a Variant does!

Comment: I'm trying to write a function that loads data from a database. I want the user to only need to provide a List of objects with properties marked by attributes. The attributes can indicate how to handle that property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't provide the information of where to get the value and say that you can handle that yourself (in the comments) I just post the part to find out the property type and leave the rest to you unless you provide additional information.

I also leave all the other type kinds to you and give you a rough idea.

```
if vProp.IsWritable then
begin
  case vProp.PropertyType.TypeKind of
    tkInteger: val := TValue.From<Integer>(...);
    tkFloat:   val := TValue.From<Double>(...);
    tkUString: val := TValue.From<string>(...);
  end;
  vProp.SetValue(newObject, val);
end;
```